# What are following sata raid drivers for?

Tags: drivers, raid, sata

I've been installing raid 1 based server and the first time i did it. I didn't know which one to choose to I chose at random (I think ICH7R/DH one). Everything worked, but disk access times were cosmic (around 20ms).
I immediately realized the driver was wrong, but i couldn't find any reference as to what each of those "ECH7XXXX" mean or what they are for.

So here's a small list of drivers, could anybody tell me what the difference between them are and what they are for? Also, what do tose "MDH" and "R/DH" mean?

```
- Intel(R) Desktop/Workstation/Server Express Chipset SATA RAID Controller
- Intel(R) Mobile Express Chipset SATA RAID Controller 
- Intel(R) ICH7MDH SATA RAID Controller
- Intel(R) ICH7R/DH SATA RAID Controller
```

I am using Asus z77-a motherboard, 2 ssd drives (that by the way give great speeds apart from access speeds in this setup). ALso I am using Win XP with F6 instalaton. The list of drivers I left are ones provided in Asus website, so I don't think any of them are built for wrong hardware, i just suspect they malfunction because wrong ones are installed.

Another thing i might add is: the reason I am even bothering with this is applications that should take seconds to start are taking a half a minute or so and that's long past the possible mirror build time, because before my current installation the PC has been running for several days.

Answer (score 0):

It's better if for you to find out the motherboard model and then read the spec. sheet to see what controller it's using.

Btw, I doubt you're installing wrong driver. The hardward ID for those controllers are different. If you try to install a wrong one it should refuse to install.

To tell which driver you should install, you can also tell us the hardware ID you found in the details page of device manager.

Comment: I am installing XP with F6 Method on Asus z77-a motherboard. I just installed `Intel(R) Desktop/Workstation/Server Express Chipset SATA RAID Controller`. Although after instalation I tested access speeds twice and got 16 and 20ms

Comment: Check the event viewer to see if there's any faulty conditions (both errors and warnings) report by the RAID controller.

Comment: A lot of print related errors and a few time sync errors, but nothing even remotely connected to motherboard, RAID or storage. I mean the PC works and SSDs work (and are setup as a single volume through bios), everything works without a single visible error or sign of corruption (I used several diagnostics tools and drives didn't show any signs of corruption), apart from the slow data access speeds.

Comment: I'm unable to figure out the problem then.

If Intel RST encounter error will create log in event logs. I was suspecting there are error in the SSD's controller so it's access mode is degraded. (Some old memories regarding DMA and PIO modes)